# How to Test if a String Has an Array Entry

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, discord.js

I'm creating a Discord bot with Discord.js that catches whenever someone swears in a message.  I have an array that's full of common swear words, abbreviations, racial and sexual slurs, etc. that I want it to catch.

```
const SwearWords = ["a##","ba##ard","bi###","c#ck","c#nt","d#ck","f#ck","gay","k#ke","n#gg","omfg","sh#t","wtf"];
```

(the array doesn't have all the hashtags, I just added them in for the post)

What I tried using originally was `if (lcMsg.includes(SwearWords)) {return;}` with `lcMsg` being `message.content.toLowerCase();` so that it can catch users swearing no matter how they capitalize it.  But that didn't work so I tried using `.entries()` and `.every()` after Google-ing an answer (and I never found any).

I imagine `.map()` would work?  I don't know because I haven't learned how to use that.  If someone could help me figure this out that'd be great.

Comment: What about this? `lcMsg.split(" ").forEach(msg=> swearWords.includes(msg))`

Comment: `let containsSwears = lcMsg.split(" ").some(s => SwearWords.indexOf(s.toLowerCase()) > -1);`

Comment: You accept an answer too quickly. Please wait at least 24 or 48 hours before accept an answer, because this will discourage other people try to post better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `.some` method will be helpful here. Combine that with your `.includes` to see if any of those words are present in the message:

```js
const SwearWords = ["a##","ba##ard","bi###","c#ck","c#nt","d#ck","f#ck","gay","k#ke","n#gg","omfg","sh#t","wtf"];

const saltyMessage = "wtf, git gud scrub";
const niceMessage = "gg wp";

function hasBadWord(msg) {
    return SwearWords.some(word => msg.includes(word));
}

console.log("Message and has swear word?:", saltyMessage, " -> ", hasBadWord(saltyMessage));
console.log("Message and has swear word?:", niceMessage, " -> ", hasBadWord(niceMessage));
```

Additionally, you can find which word the message had by using `.find` instead of `.some`:

```js
const SwearWords = ["a##","ba##ard","bi###","c#ck","c#nt","d#ck","f#ck","gay","k#ke","n#gg","omfg","sh#t","wtf"];

const saltyMessage = "wtf, git gud scrub";
const niceMessage = "gg wp";

function whichBadWord(msg) {
    return SwearWords.find(word => msg.includes(word));
}

console.log("Message and has swear word?:", saltyMessage, " -> ", whichBadWord(saltyMessage));
console.log("Message and has swear word?:", niceMessage, " -> ", whichBadWord(niceMessage));
```

Comment: This works great, thank you!!

Comment: Glad to help, but it just occurred to me that this will return true if a word contains a swear word as a substring, eg: `"Assistant manager"` would give a false positive. So use with care. You may want to look into using a regex test for this instead.

Comment: OK.  I've never used regex tests; where is a good place I could learn it?

Comment: Well there are plenty of tutorials online. I don't have a preference for any in particular. I'd say just pick one and go for it. Learning regexes is a bit daunting at first but once you know them they're amazingly helpful. [this site](https://regexone.com/) has a nice interactive tutorial, but there are many others as well.

Comment: Alright, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the function `some` and function `includes`

```
lcMsg.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').split(' ').some((w) => SwearWords.includes(w));
```

*Look how the variable `lcMsg` is being prepared to loop over its words.*